# Initial EJB RMI works but with exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb, wildfly

I'm working through an EJB tutorial where my client program invokes a method via remote stateless EJB to add a book. Upon exit the client retrieves and prints all the books from the EJB (I know it's not a good idea to store data in a list within a stateless EJB). All of this works fine, except the initial RMI also returns the following exception (I've included the full output  from the client test as well).

**Client output:**

```
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:29 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.1.4.Final
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit
Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Some book
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:44 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:44 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:44 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:45 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: EJBCLIENT000017: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:45 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@4f7d0008, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@271053e1,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=slave01:server01]} on channel Channel ID 87a6ebda (outbound) of Remoting connection 64bfbc86 to /127.0.0.1:8133 of endpoint "client-endpoint" <64bf3bbf>
Nov 29, 2016 11:34:45 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager getEJBReceiver
INFO: Could not create a connection for cluster node ClusterNode{clusterName='ejb', nodeName='slave01:server01', clientMappings=[ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='0.0.0.0', destinationPort=8080}], resolvedDestination=[Destination address=0.0.0.0, destination port=8080]} in cluster ejb
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:321)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:153)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.getEJBReceiver(RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext$EJBReceiverAssociationTask.call(ClusterContext.java:469)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext$EJBReceiverAssociationTask.call(ClusterContext.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit 
Enter Choice: 2
Book(s) entered so far: 2
1. test1
2. Some book
***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***
Book(s) entered so far: 2
1. test1
2. Some book
```

So everything with the client, other than the exception, appears to work correctly. I suspect this issue has something to do with the zero'd out node addresses, but I'm not certain. The client properties file is below (in case that configuration is incorrect).

**jboss-ejb-clients.properties:**

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
invocation.timeout=3000
reconnect.tasks.timeout=2000


# User Credentials
username=user
password=pass


# Remote Connections
remote.connections=h1,h2
remote.connection.h1.host=127.0.0.1
remote.connection.h1.port=8133
remote.connection.h1.username=user
remote.connection.h1.password=pass    
remote.connection.h2.host=127.0.0.1
remote.connection.h2.port=8134
remote.connection.h2.username=user
remote.connection.h2.password=pass


# Cluster
remote.clusters=ejb
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.timeout=2500
remote.cluster.ejb.max-allowed-connected-nodes=2
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.cluster.ejb.username=user
remote.cluster.ejb.password=pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research (and a good amount of trial and error with test code), I found a book on Safari (Java EE 7 Development with WildFly) that lead me in the right direction. I had to drop the jboss-ejb-clients.properties file and add the ejb-client configuration found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749897/clustered-ejbs-not-being-balanced-in-jboss-as-7) to my main client class.